# Selenium C# - How to Check All Links

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check all links on a page. Some questions already were asked on this topic, but for some reason none are working when I tried. One particular issue I'm having is that after going to a page and after getting all links into a list variable, when looping through them, error message shows the link to be a stale reference. Here is the code snippet:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URLPROD);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

ICollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

foreach (var link in links)
{
   if (!(link.Text.Contains("Email")) || !(link.Text == "") || !(link.Text == null) || !(link.Text.Contains("Element")))
   {
      ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", link);
      Console.WriteLine(link);
      driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", link);

      driver.Navigate().Back();

    }

}
```

Error message: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed'

What should I be doing to correct this error so that I can check each link on a page?

Comment: what is the size of `linksString`

Comment: The size of linkString is 135

Comment: Which line was causing the stale element in previous version ?

Comment: Sorry, I have to rewrite the code as I unfortunately i haven't saved the previous versions. I will try to regenerate the same error.

Comment: Please clean up your question. All the updates are making it hard to follow what you current question actually is. Just post an [mcve] of the current code you are working with and the error message you are getting.

Comment: You are right JeffC. I have reviewed the question this morning and updated it. It now asks one question. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just re-find the links.
So 1. get number of links  2. loop that number getting the links fresh each time (to avoid stale errors).

```
        var links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

        for (int i=0; i < links.Count(); i++)
        {
            var newLinks = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
            newLinks[i].Click();
            driver.Navigate().Back();
        }
```

Comment: foreach loop seems to have error. Can you please check and edit the code? Thank you.

Comment: @Sohel try it now

Comment: Thanks for correcting this Ywapon. The code is showing the following error: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'Element<a class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" href="javascript";"> could not be scrolled into view'

Comment: Get rid of the other loop you have that calls that javascript call, you don't need it now.  You don't need to scroll to the item.

Comment: There is no loop outer loop. I was using a standalone console program. When placed your code segment in Unit Test (Selenium) code, now I get the following error: : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index    - it is pointing to this line of code "newLinks[i].Click();

Comment: Probably an error of 1 just change to links.Count() -1 or something.  The point is you get the count of the links and loop that count to click each sequential link.  You should be able to debug the details from the sudo code example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177233/discussion-between-ywapom-and-sohel).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177291/discussion-between-sohel-and-ywapom).

Comment: I am accepting Ywapom's solution as an answer as I was able to resolve Stale Reference error using his feedback. Thanks Ywapom!